# SQL: How to find min value per group in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table `snapshots`:

```
domain      year  month  day
---         ---    ---   ---
google      2007   04    15
google      2005   08    31
google      2005   12    01
facebook    2006   04    15
facebook    2006   02    25
facebook    2008   01    01
```

What I want to retrieve is the first (earliest) date of each domain.

So the output should be:

```
google    2005  08  31
facebook  2006  02  25
```

I have tried the following query, but it retrieves the minimum value for each column:

```
select domain, min(year), min(month), min(day) from snapshots group by domain
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: You need to treat them as date after a concatenation and apply the MIN function.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos MySQL

Comment: If You can store `date` data in `date` type column instead separated columns...

Comment: Any other way to do it without concatenation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned you should use concatenation to create a single date and then select the lowest value.

```
select domain, MIN(CAST(CONCAT(`year`, '-'`,month`,'-',`day`) AS DATE)) from snapshots group by domain
```

Haven't tested this but this should give you an idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate the values from the date field, cast them as date and select the min date (i expect the values to be varchar in this case):

```
SELECT domain, 
MIN(CAST(CONCAT(year,'-',month,'-',day) AS date)) 
FROM snapshots 
GROUP BY domain;
```

Comment: Thanks! concatenation really simplified it.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL:

```
SELECT
    domain,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MIN(CONCAT(year,'-',month,'-',day))), '%Y') as y,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MIN(CONCAT(year,'-',month,'-',day))), '%m') as m,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MIN(CONCAT(year,'-',month,'-',day))), '%d') as d
FROM snapshots
GROUP BY domain;
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be easier solutions, but you can create a new column of date type from the three columns year, month, and day. Then get the min date as following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.domain, s.year, s.month, s.day
FROM
(
  SELECT domain, year,month,day,
       STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(`year`,'-',LPAD(`month`,2,'00'),'-',LPAD(`day`,2,'00')) ,'%Y-%m-%d') AS FullDate
    FROM snapshots
) AS s
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT domain, MIN(Fulldate) MinDate
  FROM
  (
    SELECT domain, year,month,day,
       STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(`year`,'-',LPAD(`month`,2,'00'),'-',LPAD(`day`,2,'00')) ,'%Y-%m-%d') AS FullDate
    FROM snapshots
  ) AS t
  GROUP BY domain
) AS t  ON t.MinDate = s.FullDate 
       AND t.Domain = s.Domain;
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/162d6d/18)

This will give you the exact results that you want:

```
|   domain | year | month | day |    MinDate |
|----------|------|-------|-----|------------|
|   google | 2005 |     8 |  31 | 2005-08-31 |
| facebook | 2006 |     2 |  25 | 2006-02-25 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this please and let me know if it solves your problem without concatenation? Could be made more robust with subqueries if necessary.

```
CREATE TABLE domainDate(domain CHAR(25), `year` INT, `month` INT, `day` INT);

INSERT INTO domainDate VALUES
    ('google', 2007, 04, 15),
    ('google', 2005, 08, 31),
    ('google', 2005, 12, 01),
    ('facebook', 2006, 04, 15),
    ('facebook', 2006, 02, 25),
    ('facebook', 2008, 01, 01);

SET @VDomain := '';
SELECT domain, `year`, `month`, `day` FROM domainDate HAVING @VDomain != @VDomain := domain ORDER BY domain, `year` * 10000 + `month` * 100 + `day`;
```

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 0):

You can try ranking function ROW_NUMBER()

```
CREATE TABLE domainDate(domain CHAR(25), [year] INT, [month] INT, [day] INT);

INSERT INTO domainDate VALUES
    ('google', 2007, 04, 15),
    ('google', 2005, 08, 31),
    ('google', 2005, 12, 01),
    ('facebook', 2006, 04, 15),
    ('facebook', 2006, 02, 25),
    ('facebook', 2008, 01, 01);

SELECT domain
    ,[year]
    ,[month]
    ,[day]
FROM 
(
    SELECT domain
        ,[year]
        ,[month]
        ,[day]
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY domain ORDER BY [year], [month], [day]) AS RN
    FROM domainDate
) t
WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In MS SQL you can do it this way:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES * FROM  mytable
ORDER BY row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY domain Order by year DESC, month DESC, day DESC).
```

See this fiddle-link for details: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7ad785/9