# Retaining additional Columns whilst using MIN or MAX with Group By

Tags: sql, group-by, min, self-join

First time post on stackoverflow, new to SQL (and any code in general) would appreciate some advice on a group by query I have. Based on the sample data set below I am looking to group on ID/Name and return the Min sales for each person. The difficulty I'm having is that I also want to return the REGION and QTR information associated with the lowest sales performance.

| ID | NAME | REGION | SALES | QTR. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Luke | NORTH | 45 | 1 |
| 2 | Danny | WEST | 67 | 2 |
| 3 | Elle | NORTH | 73 | 1 |
| 1 | Luke | WEST | 32 | 4 |
| 2 | Danny | EAST | 22 | 3 |
| 2 | Danny | EAST | 18 | 2 |

So essentially group to a table as below

| ID | NAME | REGION | MIN SALES | QTR. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Luke | WEST | 32 | 4 |
| 2 | Danny | EAST | 18 | 2 |
| 3 | Elle | NORTH | 73 | 1 |

If I bring in the additional columns into the group by it creates multiple rows for each individual, if I leave them out I lose the associated data.

Can anyone help, from looking online it looks like I might have to join the table back with itself, though I'm not sure how to do that.

Thanks

Tom

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL: How to find min value per group in sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46364501/sql-how-to-find-min-value-per-group-in-sql)

Comment: What's the expected result if someone has the same, lowest sales for 2 separate periods`?

Comment: You need to add which DBMS and what version are you using

Comment: @jarlh great point and not something I'd considered, i would need to think through further - I think it would mean losing the region/QTR information in those instances to retain 1 row per person

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ebb85bdb1b93e668aadc688c18351746

```
  with data(ID, NAME,   REGION, SALES,  QTR) as
    (select 1,  'Luke', 'NORTH',45, 1 from dual union all
    select 2,   'Danny','WEST', 67, 2 from dual union all
    select 3,   'Elle', 'NORTH',73, 1 from dual union all
    select 1,   'Luke', 'WEST', 32, 4 from dual union all
    select 2,   'Danny','EAST', 22, 3 from dual union all
    select 2,   'Danny','EAST', 18, 2 from dual 
    ),
    minS as (select ID , min(Sales) minsales
    from data
    group by ID)
    Select data.id, data.name,data.region,data.sales "min sales" ,data.qtr from data
    join minS on minS.ID= data.Id
    and minS.minsales= data.sales
    order by data.id
```

Comment: Thank you, very helpful, the dbfiddle site looks like a great way for me to iterate the code to learn as well

Answer (score 0):

Calculate a row_number in a sub-query, then filter on it.

```
SELECT ID, NAME, REGION, SALES AS MIN_SALES, QTR
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, NAME, REGION, SALES, QTR
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY SALES ASC) AS rn
    FROM YourTable
) q
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY id
```

And if you want MAX_SALES, then order by sales DESC (descending) in the row_number.

Comment: Thank you for the solution